# set the first element in list per default in select input angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having problem in setting the first element in my ng-repeat list in the select input,this is my code:

```
<div>
<span >OF</span> 
<select ng-model="eclatementCourante.ordreFabricationId" ng-change="dupOF(eclatementCourante.ordreFabricationId)">
    <option ng-repeat="pi in listGammeOF" value="{{pi.id}}">{{pi.numero}}  
    </option>
</select>
</div>
```

thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

you can use [ng-init](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit)

```
<select ng-init="anyVariable = anyVariable|| options[0]"  ng-model="eclatementCourante.ordreFabricationId" 
        ng-options="option.name for option in options"></select>
```